# C# MongoDB - How to add and remove item to multiple nested array elements?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document in MongoDB that looks like that:

```
{
    "Id":"123",
    "Product": "test",
    "Tags":[
        {
            "Name": "name",
            "Categories": [
                {
                    //item
                },
                {
                    //item
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "name",
            "Categories": [
                {
                    //item
                },
                {
                    //item
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I need to add a new `Item` and it needs to be added to all of the categories of the `Tags` element of that `Product` by its `Id`.
For example, when I'll insert `Item 3` the document should look like this:

```
{
    "Id":"123",
    "Product": "test",
    "Tags":[
        {
            "Name": "name",
            "Categories": [
                {
                    //item 1
                },
                {
                    //item 2
                },
                {
                    //item 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "name",
            "Categories": [
                {
                    //item 1
                },
                {
                    //item 2
                },
                {
                    //item 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and same goes for removing an item, it needs to be removed from all of the categories as well.
Is there a way to do that with the C# MongoDB Driver without pulling the object and "manually" updating them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try something like below in 2.5 driver with 3.6 version.

Finds the document with `filter` criteria and `update` which includes new [positional identifier](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to update multiple elements in array inside `UpdateOne` method.

[$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) updates all the `Tags` arrays to include new item in all `Categories` array. It acts as a placeholder for updating all elements in array.

Push

```
var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq("Id", "123");
var update = Builders<Product>.Update.Push("Tags.$[].Categories", "Item 3");
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Pull

```
var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq("Id", "123");
var update = Builders<Product>.Update.Pull("Tags.$[].Categories", "Item 3");
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Additional Information:

You can set the `ArrayFilters` options in `UpdateOptions` for applying query criteria on nested array to control what elements to update.

For example to update all the Categories in Tags array where each tag has `Name` name.

```
var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq("Id", "123");
var update = Builders<Product>.Update.Push("Tags.$[t].Categories", "Item 3");
var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>{ new ArrayFilterDefinition(new BsonDocument("t.Name", "name")) };
var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions({ArrayFilters = arrayFilters});
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error on the `Push` solution: `"A write operation resulted in an error.\r\n  cannot use the part (Tags of Tags.$[].Categories) to traverse the element`

Comment: It looks like you are not on the latest 3.6 version. Execute `db.version()` in shell to check the version.

Comment: I&#39;ve already checked it, version 3.6.1... I run it in Robo mongo.

Comment: Didn't get a chance to test c# code but I was able to run queries in shell for the sample data provided. Not sure where the error is. Try looking at the data you are trying to update and run queries in shell. May be some of your documents are missing Categories or Tags and both are type of arrays. Try `db.collection_name.find({"Id":"123"}, {"$push":{"Tags.$[].Categories":"Item 3"}});` in shell.

Comment: I copy pasted your query into my Robo Mongo query editor and it gives this error: `Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unsupported projection option: $push: { Tags.$[].Categories: \"Item 3\" }",
 "code" : 2,
 "codeName" : "BadValue"
}`

Comment: Something is very strange... I even copied the sample query from MongoDB's documentation with their sample collection as well from [Update Nested Arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#position-nested-arrays) and it gives an error `cannot use the part (grades of grades.$[].questions.$[score]) to traverse the element`. But when I run `db.version() ` in Robo Mongo it returns 3.6.1. I must be missing something here...

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was the issue here ?

Comment: Yes. Turn out it was a mongo db settings issue, you need to run this command `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )` in order to be able to use hthe new array filters...

Comment: I wanted to add that this [answer ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622030/1057052) ended up giving me the correct result!