# UpdateMany - ArrayFilterDefinition c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to update just a few nested documents on my .Net Application, but I don't know exactly how to do that.

Here is one of the topics I've been searching after making this question:

[C# - MongoDB - Update an element inside a Nested Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180188/c-sharp-mongodb-update-an-element-inside-a-nested-document)

**DataBase Object: **

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d03a6f5fba276260c4911bd"),
    "costumerId" : ObjectId("5c050cdefba2771eac58c84b"),
    "order" : 106376,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemId" : 10226905,
            "date" : ISODate("2018-11-30T14:00:00.000Z"),
            "description" : "itemA",
            "new" : true,
        }, 
        {
            "itemId" : 10226906,
            "date" : ISODate("2018-11-30T14:00:00.000Z"),
            "description" : "itemB",
            "new" : true,
        }, 
        {
            "itemId" : 10226907,
            "date" : ISODate("2018-11-23T14:00:00.000Z"),
            "description" : "ItemC",
            "new" : true,
        }, 
        {
            "itemId" : 10226908,
            "date" : ISODate("2018-11-23T14:00:00.000Z"),
            "description" : "ItemD",
            "new" : false,
        }, 
    ]
}
```

**MongoDB Update Query:**

```
db.CostumerProducts.update(
    {costumerId: 106376},
    {
        $set:{'items.$[element].new': true}
    }, 
    {
        multi:true, 
        arrayFilters: [ 
        {
            'element.itemId':{
                $in:[10226905,10226906,10226907]
             }
        }]
    })
```

**C# Update Query using MongoDB driver:**

```
var arrayObjects = List<int>{10226905,10226906,10226907};
var filter = Builders<CostumerProductsObject>.Filter.And(new[]  
{
    new FilterDefinitionBuilder<CostumerProductsObject>().Eq(p=>p.costumerId, costumerId), 
    new FilterDefinitionBuilder<CostumerProductsObject>().Eq(p=>p.order, order),
});

var set = Builders<ItemsObject>.Update.Set("items.$[element].new", true);

var arrayFilter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<ItemsObject>().In(a=>a.itemId, itemsArray);

 using (var db = new MongoContextInfra())
{
    db.Set<CostumerProductsObject>(CollectionName).UpdateMany(filter, 
         set,
         new UpdateOptions
         {
             ArrayFilters = null
         });
}
```

I expect to update just the three items into "arrayObjects" variable.

Can you show me some code or help me fixing mine so I can make this update?
thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621667/how-to-update-item-from-array-nested-within-array/51622030#51622030

Comment: Thanks @mickl I'll try this one and make you noticed.