# How to update deeply nested array with C# MongoDB.Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have such model:

```
{  
   "_id":"5b90eea8c02e062be2888446",
   "storeGuid":"e97d4730-9b8a-49ed-be87-caf4054439aa",
   "storeId":"0",
   "storeDbName":"0",
   "tenant":"dev",
   "configGroup":[  
      {  
         "groupName":"peopleCounter",
         "config":[  
            {  
               "key":"averageWaitPeriodTime",
               "value":"60",
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "groupName":"sessionMonitor",
         "config":[  
            {  
               "key":"testKey1",
               "value":"987",
            },
            {  
               "key":"testKey2",
               "value":"123",
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to update `value` for `"key":"testKey2"`

I have such update statement:

```
await coll.UpdateOneAsync(
    x => x.StoreGuid == storeGuid
         && x.ConfigGroup.Any(y => y.GroupName == groupName
                                   && y.Config.Any(z => z.Key == model.Key)),
    Builders<StoreModel>.Update.Set(x => x.ConfigGroup[-1].Config[-1].Value, model.Value));
```

When i try to update for example `groupName` using such filter `ConfigGroup[-1]` it works.

But in the case when we have `ConfigGroup[-1].Config[-1]` it does not work.

I know two options how to update the value:

- just update whole list using `ConfigGroup[-1].Config`
- or specify concrete indexes for filter like `ConfigGroup[configGroupIndex].Config[configKeyIndex].Value`

But i want to know why it does not work with `-1` index.
And how to do it properly.

Please answer using **c# MongoDB.Driver**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe  there is type safe solution. Also using multiple positional operator is only supported from 3.6 mongo version via array filters syntax. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009922/c-sharp-mongodb-how-to-add-and-remove-item-to-multiple-nested-array-elements/48014343#48014343) is one such solution if you are interested.

Comment: @Veeram Thx for your comment. So far i didn't find type safe solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason why it does not work with multiply `'-1'` because it is the same as [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) `$`.
In official documentation under the subject of "Nested Arrays" we can see next:

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse
>   more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested
>   within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is
>   a single value

From **MongoDb 3.6** there are new features that allow to work with nested arrays.

[The all positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

[The filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

> The filtered positional operator `$[<identifier>]` identifies the array
>   elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update
>   operation

So, using the filtered position operator my code looks like this now:

```
await coll.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.StoreGuid == storeGuid,
    Builders<StoreModel>.Update.Set("configGroup.$[g].config.$[c].value", model.Value),
    new UpdateOptions
    {
        ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
        {
            new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("g.groupName", groupName)),
            new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("c.key", model.Key))
        }
    });
```

Comment: finally well described answer with example!