# How to update a field "type-safe" in a deeply nested array with C# MongoDb driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to update individual fields in a deeply nested array.

```
    public class Maker
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public List<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Updating a field in a level-1 array works like a charm. **Updating a field in a level-2 array fails.**

```
 public void UpdateNestedArrayFields()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
        var makers = db.GetCollection<Maker>("makers");

        // Create a maker and add a vehicle
        var newPart = new Part() { Id = 34, Name = "Wheel" };
        var newVehicle = new Vehicle() { Id = 17, Price = 1000, Parts = new List<Part>() { newPart } };
        var newMaker = new Maker() { Id = 5, Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>() { newVehicle } };

        // Update vehicle's price (WORKS)
        makers.FindOneAndUpdate(
            m => m.Id == newMaker.Id && m.Vehicles.Any(v => v.Id == newVehicle.Id),
            Builders<Maker>.Update.Set(m => m.Vehicles[-1].Price, 2000));

        // Update part's name (**FAILS**)
        makers.FindOneAndUpdate(
            m => m.Id == newMaker.Id && m.Vehicles.Single(v => v.Id == newVehicle.Id).Parts.Any(p=> p.Id == newPart.Id),
            Builders<Maker>.Update.Set(m => m.Vehicles[-1].Parts[-1].Name, "Tire"));
    }
```

I understand that multiple positional operators are not supported, so my last line (m.Vehicles[-1].Parts[-1].Name) is kind of crap.

Obviously I am not the only one having this problem and I found different solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311508/how-to-update-deeply-nested-array-with-c-sharp-mongodb-driver?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009922/c-sharp-mongodb-how-to-add-and-remove-item-to-multiple-nested-array-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, **none of them is type safe**. The resulting code is pretty ugly and error prone.

So I was wondering:
**Is there any way to redesign my code so it is type safe?**

I am using MongoDb 4.0.9 and C# driver 2.11.5.

**Edit (01-11-2020):**
For anybody interested, I found this really nice extension by Massimiliano Kraus, which is a bit outdated (2017), but is still working and turned out to be a huge help. Thank you, Massimiliano! [MongoDB.DeepUpdater.CSharp](https://github.com/massimilianokraus/MongoDB.DeepUpdater.CSharp)

Comment: Please try this and let me know, the Tire is not Maker type it is a Part type so if you change Maker to Part type and try (Builders<Maker> to Builders<Part>), it should works, let me know so I can investigate more or leave an answer.

Comment: @maytham: You want me to use Builders<Part>.Update... instead of Builders<Maker>.Update...in my last command? No, that won't even compile. I need to update a Part inside a Maker. I can't just update a "standalone" Part. Could you copy my code to a new console application and try your suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

in order to update nested arrays like this, you need to use the [array filters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#nested-arrays) feature of mongodb.

the needed mongo query is this:

```
db.Maker.update(
    {
        "_id": 5
    },
    {
        $set: { 'Vehicles.$[v].Parts.$[p].Name': 'Tyre' }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            { 'v._id': { $eq: 17 } },
            { 'p._id': { $eq: 34 } }
        ]
    }
)
```

the c# driver is not capable of generating the above in a strongly-typed fashion.
have a look at [this article](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110) for an alternative semi-typed solution to running advanced queries like the above.

Comment: Good morning and thank you for your contribution. The article you referred to shows a solution equal to the links I had already posted in my question. So I guess there is indeed no 100% type-safe solution, which is a pity. I wish the creatos of the C# driver could improve this at some point. Please let me wait a few more days to see if anyone has a nifty idea before I give you the bonus.

Comment: @Ingmar you could alternatively use a utility method like [this](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/9566304320ebd4b94919cf404b9e0806b068e357/MongoDB.Entities/Utilities/Prop.cs#L97) to turn a typed member expression to a positional filter string that can be handed to the c# driver, but the resulting code would be less readable/ugly compared to the template/tag replacement idea on that article.

Comment: :Thank you again for your suggestions.I kept on searching for "built-in" ways to solve my problem type-safely. There really seems to be no way with the current c# driver. This is  a pitty. However, I did find a really nice NuGet Package. I am going to add the link to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other possible and more typed version of typed nested array update.
it not fully typed, but it is closer to what u need.

its also using **`ArrayFilters`** but in more typed fashion

this code is coming straight from application that I'm working on.

```
var filter = Builders<EventModel>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, eventId);

var settingsPath = @$"{nameof(EventModel.EventLayout)}.{nameof(EventLayoutSetting.Pages)}.$[page].{nameof(Page.Components)}.$[component].{nameof(Component.Settings)}";
var update = Builders<EventModel>.Update.
                     Set(settingsPath, settings);

var dbResult = await eventsCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, new UpdateOptions 
            {
                ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition> 
                {
                    new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument> (new BsonDocument($"page.{nameof(Page.PageId)}",pageId)),
                    new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument> (new BsonDocument($"component.{nameof(Component.ComponentId)}",componentId))
                }
            });
```